# Django Select Widget variables

Tags: django, forms, templates, select, widget

Any one know how to get the Select Widget choices in a template.

I have done theses. I am overriding admin templates and I could just change the admin form code but I don't want to for app integrity purposes.

```
{{field.choices}}
```

Yields nothing.

```
{%for i in field%}{{i.choices}}{%endfor%}
```

Yeilds ()

I need to access this var from the template. 
I want to change the select field into radios.

Comment: You should change default widget of your form field to [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

Comment: Great answer, and thank you, but the problem is I don't want to change the admin forms, I am messing with admin.

Comment: Also Daniel, I believe that you are censoring things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `field` is a `BoundField`,

```
{{ field.field.widget.choices }}
```

should get you the choices iterable.

Comment: You are the PERSON, thanks so much. That works great, not that anyone should ever do what I'm doing.